# Netbeans Version Control File Color Codes?

Tags: version-control, ide, netbeans, netbeans6.7

I'm trying to find a legend that can help explain the different colors NetBeans uses to describe the state of a file.

Some of my file colors are:

- Grey
- Blue
- Green
- Any others I have yet to discover

If it helps, I'm using Netbeans 6.7 with CVS. What are these colors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Green means new.
- Blue means modified.
- Grey means ignored and/or deleted. (Documentation contradicts the tooltip hint!)

If you go into the *View* menu, you can turn on *Show Versioning Labels*. That will put text next to each file explaining its state (and what each color represents).

[image]
<sub>Image from [Netbeans.org](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#viewFileStatus)</sub>

Comment: Your image seems to be dead. Do you remember what it was?

Comment: @Laurel I assume it was a picture of the labels in action. If anyone can take a picture of what this currently looks like I would appreciate the edit with a new picture.

Answer (score 2):

Using the online help and searching for icon/icons and or badge/badges should give you the information you want.

Alternatively take a look at [BadgedIcons](http://wiki.netbeans.org/BadgedIcons) which at least explains some of the colors and icons (e.g. for version control)