# Netbeans IDE: Color, highlight or badge arbitrary files in projects window?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

Is there a way (natively or via a plugin) to arbitrary highlight or provide a background color to files displayed in the projects window?

For example, it would be awesome if I could visually indicate all of my config classes in this project view by giving them a light yellow background.

[image]

And, of course, I wouldn't want to mess with the version control colors as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1131940/225217).

Is anybody doing something like this?